# Why should we not Schedule an interrupt on a borrowed thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout, cancellation, interruption

Here is the snippet from book *Java Concurrency in Practice*:

```
//Scheduling an interrupt on a borrowed thread. Don’t do this.

private static final ScheduledExecutorService cancelExec = ...;

public static void timedRun(Runnable r,long timeout, TimeUnit unit) {
    final Thread taskThread = Thread.currentThread();
    cancelExec.schedule(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { taskThread.interrupt(); }
    }, timeout, unit);
    r.run();
}
```

The author says:

> This is an appealingly simple approach, but it violates the rules: you
>   should know a thread’s interruption policy before interrupting it.
>   Since timedRun can be called from an arbitrary thread, it cannot know
>   the calling thread’s interruption policy. **If the task completes before
>   the timeout**, the **cancellation task** that interrupts the thread in which
>   timedRun was called could go off after timedRun has returned to its
>   caller. We don’t know what code will be running when that happens, but
>   the result won’t be good. (It is possible but surprisingly tricky to
>   eliminate this risk by using the ScheduledFuture returned by schedule
>   to cancel the cancellation task.)
>
> Further, if the task is not responsive to interruption, timedRun will
>   not return until the task finishes, which may be long after the
>   desired timeout (or even not at all). A timed run service that doesn’t
>   return after the specified time is likely to be irritating to its
>   callers.

My questions:

1. What does **timeout** mean?
2. What is **cancellation task**?

Answer (score 3):

The timeout means that `taskThread` has an allotted time interval to run the task before it gets interrupted. The cancellation task is the dedicated task that does the interrupting (on a separate thread).

Dangers here are:

- The code is interrupting a thread rather than cancelling a task. The thread being interrupted might be part of a thread pool and could have finished the task already and be in the middle of some entirely different task.
- The task being interrupted might not use the interruption appropriately as an indicator to finish up its work, or if could be doing something like blocking I/O where it can't check the interrupt status, so there's no assurance in general that the timeout is effective.

Comment: I think "The timeout means that the **thread** has an alloted time interval for the thread to run in" should be "The timeout means that the **task** has an alloted time interval for the thread to run in". And what is alloted?